# How to connect Remote Q manager(on docker) from windows?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, esb

I have an environment of MQ on docker container. I have created Queue manager QM_TEST with the help of following link :
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21623113

I can not connect the queue manager from MQ explorer from windows. Following error of channel is coming when connecting Q manager.

Could not establish a connection to the queue manager. Channel name not recognized (AMQ4871)
  Severity: 10 (Warning)
  Explanation: The attempt to connect to the queue manager failed. The queue manager did not recognize the channel name.
[Snap1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nODYi.jpg) [Snap2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX3sm.jpg) [Snap3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p76RI.jpg) [Snap4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMVBZ.jpg) [Snap5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q4rF.jpg)

```
AMQ5052I: The queue manager task 'QPUBSUB-CTRLR' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The publish/subscribe utility task manager has started the QPUBSUB-CTRLR task.
This task has now started 1 times.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqzmut0.c : 1629 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62260.30) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.722Z)
                    ArithInsert2(1)
                    CommentInsert1(TOPIC-TREE)

AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'TOPIC-TREE' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The critical utility task manager has started the TOPIC-TREE task. This task
has now started 1 times.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqzmut0.c : 1629 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62260.34) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.722Z)
                    ArithInsert2(1)
                    CommentInsert1(MULTICAST)

AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'MULTICAST' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The critical utility task manager has started the MULTICAST task. This task has
now started 1 times.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqzmut0.c : 1629 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62260.31) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.722Z)
                    ArithInsert2(1)
                    CommentInsert1(RESOURCE_MONITOR)

AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'RESOURCE_MONITOR' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The critical utility task manager has started the RESOURCE_MONITOR task. This
task has now started 1 times.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqzmut0.c : 1629 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62260.33) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.723Z)
                    ArithInsert2(1)
                    CommentInsert1(PRESERVED-Q)

AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'PRESERVED-Q' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The critical utility task manager has started the PRESERVED-Q task. This task
has now started 1 times.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqzmut0.c : 1629 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62299.5) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuf0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.723Z)
                    ArithInsert2(1)
                    CommentInsert1(QPUBSUB-QUEUE-NLCACHE)

AMQ5052I: The queue manager task 'QPUBSUB-QUEUE-NLCACHE' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The publish/subscribe utility task manager has started the
QPUBSUB-QUEUE-NLCACHE task. This task has now started 1 times.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqzmut0.c : 1629 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62299.7) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuf0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.724Z)
                    ArithInsert2(1)
                    CommentInsert1(PUBSUB-DAEMON)

AMQ5052I: The queue manager task 'PUBSUB-DAEMON' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The publish/subscribe utility task manager has started the PUBSUB-DAEMON task.
This task has now started 1 times.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqzmut0.c : 1629 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62299.7) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuf0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.724Z)
                    CommentInsert1(IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Controller)

AMQ5975I: 'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Controller' has started.

EXPLANATION:
'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Controller' has started.
ACTION:
None.
----- cmqxzmup.c : 3951 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62260.32) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuc0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.726Z)
                    ArithInsert2(1)
                    CommentInsert1(Q-DELETION)

AMQ5051I: The queue manager task 'Q-DELETION' has started.

EXPLANATION:
The critical utility task manager has started the Q-DELETION task. This task
has now started 1 times.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqzmut0.c : 1629 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62299.8) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuf0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.731Z)
                    CommentInsert1(IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Fan Out Task)

AMQ5975I: 'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Fan Out Task' has started.

EXPLANATION:
'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Fan Out Task' has started.
ACTION:
None.
----- cmqxzmup.c : 383 --------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62299.9) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuf0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.733Z)
                    CommentInsert1(IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Command Task)

AMQ5975I: 'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Command Task' has started.

EXPLANATION:
'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Command Task' has started.
ACTION:
None.
----- cmqxzmup.c : 383 --------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62299.10) User(mqm) Program(amqzmuf0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.735Z)
                    CommentInsert1(IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Publish Task)

AMQ5975I: 'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Publish Task' has started.

EXPLANATION:
'IBM MQ Distributed Pub/Sub Publish Task' has started.
ACTION:
None.
----- cmqxzmup.c : 383 --------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62321.1) User(mqm) Program(amqzmgr0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.746Z)
                    ArithInsert1(62332)
                    CommentInsert1(SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ)

AMQ5022I: The channel initiator has started. ProcessId(62332).

EXPLANATION:
The channel initiator process has started.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqzmgr0.c : 2934 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62321.1) User(mqm) Program(amqzmgr0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.749Z)
                    ArithInsert1(62335)
                    CommentInsert1(SYSTEM.CMDSERVER.1)

AMQ5024I: The command server has started. ProcessId(62335).

EXPLANATION:
The command server process has started.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqzmgr0.c : 2943 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62332.1) User(mqm) Program(runmqchi)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.798Z)
                    CommentInsert1(SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ)

AMQ8024I: IBM MQ channel initiator started.

EXPLANATION:
The channel initiator for queue SYSTEM.CHANNEL.INITQ has been started.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqrimna.c : 866 --------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:21:34 - Process(62324.1) User(mqm) Program(amqfqpub)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:21:34.800Z)
                    CommentInsert1(QM_TEST)

AMQ5806I: Queued Publish/Subscribe Daemon started for queue manager QM_TEST.

EXPLANATION:
Queued Publish/Subscribe Daemon started for queue manager QM_TEST.
ACTION:
None.
----- cmqxfcxc.c : 1397 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:22:16 - Process(62321.1) User(mqm) Program(amqzmgr0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:22:16.457Z)
                    ArithInsert1(62392)
                    CommentInsert1(TCP.LISTENER)

AMQ5026I: The listener 'TCP.LISTENER' has started. ProcessId(62392).

EXPLANATION:
The listener process has started.
ACTION:
None.
----- amqzmgr0.c : 2951 -------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:22:25 - Process(62392.1) User(mqm) Program(runmqlsr)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:22:25.488Z)
                    ArithInsert1(1414) ArithInsert2(98)
                    CommentInsert1(bind)
                    CommentInsert2(TCP/IP)
                    CommentInsert3(:)

AMQ9218E: The TCP/IP listener program could not bind to port number 1414.

EXPLANATION:
An attempt to bind the TCP/IP socket to the listener port was unsuccessful.
ACTION:
The failure could be due to another program, including other MQ listeners,
using the same port number. The return code from the 'bind' call for port :1414
was 98. Record these values and tell the systems administrator.
----- amqclita.c : 748 --------------------------------------------------------
06/14/19 05:22:25 - Process(62321.1) User(mqm) Program(amqzmgr0)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:22:25.493Z)
                    ArithInsert1(62392)
                    CommentInsert1(TCP.LISTENER)

AMQ5027I: The listener 'TCP.LISTENER' has ended. ProcessId(62392).

EXPLANATION:
The listener process has ended.
ACTION:
None.
```

Could not establish a connection to the queue manager. Channel name not recognized (AMQ4871)
  Severity: 10 (Warning)
  Explanation: The attempt to connect to the queue manager failed. The queue manager did not recognize the channel name.

Comment: What channel did you specify in mq explorer?

Comment: Default channel SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN

Comment: Did you add SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN channel to your queue manager?

Comment: YES I have added channel to queue manager

Comment: are these commands also need to run set CHLAUTH(*) TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('nobody','*MQADMIN')
set CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.ADMIN.*) TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('nobody')

Comment: You need to look at the AMQERR01.LOG under the qmgrs/QM_TEST/errors location to see what is logged.

Comment: 06/14/19 05:22:25 - Process(62392.1) User(mqm) Program(runmqlsr)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(QM_TEST)
                    Time(2019-06-14T05:22:25.488Z)
                    ArithInsert1(1414) ArithInsert2(98)
                    CommentInsert1(bind)
                    CommentInsert2(TCP/IP)
                    CommentInsert3(:)

Comment: AMQ9218E: The TCP/IP listener program could not bind to port number 1414.
EXPLANATION:
An attempt to bind the TCP/IP socket to the listener port was unsuccessful.
ACTION:
The failure could be due to another program, including other MQ listeners,
using the same port number. The return code from the 'bind' call for port :1414
was 98. Record these values and tell the systems administrator.

Comment: Do you have more than one queue manger running in the container. That error shows the listener in 1414 for QM_TEST could not start because something else already has it open.   Check the logs for the other queue manager.

Comment: Can we run two queue manager on single port

Comment: Other Qmanager log
EXPLANATION:
The requested operation failed because the program could not find a definition
of channel 'SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN'.
ACTION:Check that the name is specified correctly and the channel definition is
available.
----- amqrcoba.c : 1340 ---
 Process(313.60) User(root) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(ibmmqdkrdev) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.1.0) QMgr(ibmmqdkrdev)

Comment: Not unless you have multiple interfaces and you can specify a different IPADDR per listener.

Comment: Paste those logs in your question.   Just put ``` three on lines around the logs so they keep the format.

Comment: error logs Snapshots added to post

Comment: Putting screen shots of ascii is not what you should do.   Just paste the info in the question.   See my last comment for how to keep the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that the channel has not been defined on the queue manager. If you believe that the channel is already defined on the queue manager, another reason could be that your client (MQ Explorer in this case) is not actually connecting to the queue manager you think it is connecting to. In which case, the channel is not defined because it is the wrong queue manager.

The default channel that MQ Explorer uses is not defined by default on a queue manager in order to ensure that it is not open to abuse by an unauthorized user.

If you look in the queue manager `AMQERR01.LOG` you will see a similar error message which also lists the channel name that does not exist.

To define the channel, use the `runmqsc` tool on the queue manager machine, and type in the following MQSC command.

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) DESCR('Channel for MQ Explorer connectivity')
```

Comment: Dear check snapshots in post , already run **DEFINE CHANNEL(SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) DESCR('Channel for MQ Explorer connectivity')**   any thing which is to be run extra

Comment: If you've got another queue manager listening on port 1414, then THAT is the queue manager reporting that it does not have the channel. Use a different port for your listener.